# Could the email of a new user be available in his profile by default

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-declined, new-users

I reckon many new users look for quick solutions and do not spend much time setting up their account. They do propose questions interesting to the community but then maybe are not present to accept the answer ... or other circumstances in which it would be handy if one was able to contact them ...

Of course the option should be there to determine for yourself which and if your email should be available publicly, but it could prove handy to make the email of the signup available by default.

**Edit:** So I'm **not suggesting personal contact**, and **neither privacy violation**, new users that **did not read** that their **email** is in their **profile** or go there to **hide it** if they want **should be contactable** ... I did not know that there is an automatism that notifies them of answers and the value of accepting one ... that's why the answer of mega6382 was accepted, but it's a total different issue.

Comment: Please no. This sounds like a great way to open these new users to unwanted messages. If you need to contact someone,  comment on one of their posts....

Comment: (Also... why dont you have your email visible in your profile, if you think it would help so much ?)

Comment: it was just a question, I didn't notice my email is not there but I'm fairly easy 'reachable' ... it would only expose the new users to emails, until they care for their account ... that would give someone a possibility to correct or involve them someway ...

Comment: Indeed it was just a question, not sure why you say this.... but anyway, your question is about giving away people's contact information, not necessarily  with them being aware of it... definitely not great... and again, if you need to correct or involve them: comment on their posts.

Comment: thats my point, if they are not aware its a good thing for S.O. members to get to them directly (it would take one email and they are aware), and if they are, for gods sake give users the freedom to expose themselves as they please !! you know how much clutter in comments to new users, absolutely useless to know, except for the new user ..

Comment: the fact that their email is available in their profile, and that they can hide this should be noted with the subscription !

Comment: Guy's I intend this the other way around ... never found a post of a newby with a brilliant answer but the guy hasn't logged for the last six months ... of course a guy like Makoto should be able to keep silly requests of his back, but I'm sure he takes care of his profile !

Comment: You mean so that they can be told how bad their so called "questions" are?  Like this one where the new user hasn't even asked any question at all? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47249336/typo3-linkhandler-configuration-for-rte - somebody really should contact that guy and tell him the difference between a statement and a question.

Comment: "and neither privacy violation" - yes, you *are* suggesting a privacy violation unless users are explicitly told that the email address they use when registering will be shown publicly. It's a really bad idea to "default to privacy invasion".

Comment: @ Jon Skeet , it should be explicitly told ... are you not more concerned that the content of SO is pertinent and worthwhile ?

Comment: @webMan - So, I see that you are not used to some of the constructs of Stack Overflow, but asking if Jon Skeet is concerned about SO content has got to be the most ridiculous question I have ever seen here. That aside, there is no mutual exclusion, we can have pertinent and worthwhile content at SO while at the same time protecting user's privacy.

Comment: @ Travis J well lets have a tickbox be checked that allows the exposure of the email in the profile upon setting a new account, and the new user may uncheck it ... I bet that the guy I'd like to contact does not read up to that point ...

Comment: @JonSkeet even if "users are explicitly told" it's not enough. 99.9999% of the people don't really read those things, then come and complain about privacy breech when finding out their email is public. ;)

Comment: @ShadowWizard: Yes, I would disagree with even that suggestion too :)

Comment: @webMan: "I bet that the guy I'd like to contact does not read up to that point" - in other words, you want to allow invasion of privacy by default, and if a user doesn't read the fine print, you don't care about their privacy. The expectation of a user *not* to be contacted by default trumps your expectation of being able to contact a user by default, IMO. Please accept the voting on this suggestion as an indication that what you believe would be a good default would actually be a very unpopular default.

Comment: @Jon Skeet please note that I already accepted the answer of mega6382 that explains why it's not a good idea ... I stated the question with sound reasoning so see no point in witholding my answers on specific comments ...

Comment: that said, of course I appreciate privacy, enough to think about one's own privacy, I'm happy to be able to be incognito although I do not chose to ...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No regular answerer on Stack Overflow have time to engage every new user, nor is it their job. And none of them are going to bother sending emails to them.

> many new users look for quick solutions and do not spend much time setting up their account. They do propose questions interesting to the community but then maybe are not present to accept the answer

But there is already a system which alerts a user to accept an answer, and that is why it is discouraged to keep asking someone to accept an answer. Thus allowing to contact them via email just for that is not an ideal solution.

P.S. Also, making someone's email publicly available without their consent is not a good idea, as it can expose them to spam emails, etc.

Comment: I don't know what users are commenting on, I see moslty experienced users boosting their skils, I was talking about beginners that do not even take care of their account ... every other person may setup his account ...